# how to search and access sub-element and structure in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, element

I have this dict (json) in python and would like to reduce it

```
{
   "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF":{
      "priceDimensions":{
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"1024",
            "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
            "beginRange":"0",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0240000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.QUZRP4P8Y4":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"51200",
            "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
            "beginRange":"1024",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0236000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.YJ98HAVVPP":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"inf",
            "description":"$0.0228 per GB",
            "beginRange":"512000",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0228000000"
            }
         }
      },
      "sku":"M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU",
      "effectiveDate":"2019-11-01T00:00:00Z",
      "offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF",
      "termAttributes":{

      }
   }
}
```

Given this above structure I would like to just return the "priceDimensions" without those "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU..." tags.

```
{
   "priceDimensions":[
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"1024",
         "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
         "beginRange":"0",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0240000000"
         }
      },
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"51200",
         "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
         "beginRange":"1024",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0236000000"
         }
      },
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"inf",
         "description":"$0.0228 per GB",
         "beginRange":"512000",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0228000000"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would then have to search in it to find the pricePerUnit for a value in a range (between beginRange and endRange)

Comment: Do you simply want `{"priceDimensions": list(d["priceDimensions"].values())}`?

Comment: Yes, @Chris well said! How do I do this in Python? Preferably with standard/common import.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear what you're looking for, but this should give you the json without the tags:

```
new_json = {'M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF':{'priceDimensions':[*your_json['M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF']['priceDimensions'].values()]}}
# or, if you want to get rid of M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF too
new_json = {'priceDimensions':[*your_json['M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF']['priceDimensions'].values()]}
```

EDIT: since the first key is variable, let's iterate through it and dump into a list

```
# New json with multiple first keys
your_json = {
   "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF1":{
      "priceDimensions":{
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"1024",
            "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
            "beginRange":"0",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0240000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.QUZRP4P8Y4":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"51200",
            "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
            "beginRange":"1024",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0236000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.YJ98HAVVPP":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"inf",
            "description":"$0.0228 per GB",
            "beginRange":"512000",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0228000000"
            }
         }
      },
      "sku":"M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU",
      "effectiveDate":"2019-11-01T00:00:00Z",
      "offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF",
      "termAttributes":{

      }
   },
   "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF2":{
      "priceDimensions":{
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"1024",
            "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
            "beginRange":"0",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0240000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.QUZRP4P8Y4":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"51200",
            "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
            "beginRange":"1024",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0236000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.YJ98HAVVPP":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"inf change",
            "description":"$0.0228 per GB change",
            "beginRange":"512000",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0228000000"
            }
         }
      },
      "sku":"M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU",
      "effectiveDate":"2019-11-01T00:00:00Z",
      "offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF",
      "termAttributes":{

      }
   }
}
```

```
# The for loop

upd8 = []

for k in your_json.keys():
  upd8.append({'priceDimensions':[*your_json[k]['priceDimensions'].values()]})

upd8
```

Hope this works better for your use case!

Comment: That works perfectly in this case but I don't always know this tag ahead ['M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF']... how can I remove it entirely from that command?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reverted to doing loops and here is what I came up that works.

```
   priceDimensions = []
    for k,v in l.items():
        for a,b in v['priceDimensions'].items():
            priceDimensions.append(b)

    print({'priceDimensions': priceDimensions})
```

Here is a test code;

```
import json

my_json = {
   "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF":{
      "priceDimensions":{
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"1024",
            "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
            "beginRange":"0",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0240000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.QUZRP4P8Y4":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"51200",
            "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
            "beginRange":"1024",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0236000000"
            }
         },
         "M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU.JRTCKXETXF.YJ98HAVVPP":{
            "unit":"GB-Mo",
            "endRange":"inf",
            "description":"$0.0228 per GB",
            "beginRange":"512000",
            "pricePerUnit":{
               "USD":"0.0228000000"
            }
         }
      },
      "sku":"M9D34X8ZHECCKKRU",
      "effectiveDate":"2019-11-01T00:00:00Z",
      "offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF",
      "termAttributes":{

      }
   }
}

priceDimensions = []
for k,v in my_json.items():
  for a,b in v['priceDimensions'].items():
    priceDimensions.append(b)

new_json = {'priceDimensions': priceDimensions}

print(new_json)
```

And output:

```
{
   "priceDimensions":[
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"1024",
         "description":"$0.0240 per GB",
         "beginRange":"0",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0240000000"
         }
      },
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"51200",
         "description":"$0.0236 per GB",
         "beginRange":"1024",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0236000000"
         }
      },
      {
         "unit":"GB-Mo",
         "endRange":"inf",
         "description":"$0.0228 per GB",
         "beginRange":"512000",
         "pricePerUnit":{
            "USD":"0.0228000000"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```